# Django Custom User Migration

Tags: django

I've got a project where I'm still using the old auth_user and profile and I would like use Django 1.8 migrations to move this over to a custom user model.

I've found plenty of instructions for how to do this with South as most people did this back in Django 1.5. Unfortunately it looks like South worked quite differently to the built in migrations in this situation.

In particular I can't see a way for a Django migration to move a model out of one app (auth) into my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When we did it, we did it in two steps. We moved to Django 1.6 and dealt with the user model. Then we moved to Django 1.7 after completing the move to AbstractUser from auth_user, to convert to using Django's migrations rather than South. Moving one version at a time is usually much easier, and I would recommend it.

Comment: You are right that we should have done this long ago. Unfortunately the code has been migrated onto Django 1.6, then 1.7 then 1.8 without addressing the user model. I think that I'm actually just going to have to write some SQL by hand.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Caktus has a lot of experience with this. Given your post, you may have run across this, but even though this is South based it'll save you a lot of headaches: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/